# Link to Homepage is forwardslash

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, url

Im have the default routing and write a link to the Homepage in my view

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Index" ,"Home")%>">Link</a>
```

The generated content is a forward slash.

```
<a href="/">Link</a>
```

This link works in Firefox but in IE8 no request is sent to the server when the link is clicked.

Is a forward slash a valid content in a link?

**EDIT:**

OMG, I tried to have an image inside the link but actually put an input type image there. The funny think is that it worked in Firefox.
Thats how my linked looked like:

```
 <a href="/"> <input type="image" src="/Images/buttons/btn_buy_more.gif" alt="" /> </a>
```

I will leave this question here so you have somebody to laugh about.

Comment: It definitely is valid content. Is there anything else attached to the link JavaScript wise? Can you post a live example?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me in IE8. I would do as Pekka suggests and look for other sources to the problem.

Comment: This is why you should always post your real code, not some untested, simplified example which you just assume will show the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Url.Action` isn't *supposed* to send a request to the server. It just generates a link address. Look at the generated URI in the HTML source of the rendered page. I'll bet it's the same in both browsers.

What I *think* you mean is that *clicking* the link is behaving differently for you. To figure out why, use Fiddler to examine the request the browser sends and the server's response.